# is it possible for a ruby module to get the directory of the file that defined a class that included the module?

Tags: ruby, directory, module

i've got a module and a class that includes the module. these are not defined in the same file, or in the same folder. i want the module to get the directory that the class is defined in.

```
# ./modules/foo.rb
module Foo
  def self.included(obj)
    obj_dirname = # ??? what goes here?
    puts "the class that included Foo was defined in this directory: #{obj_dirname}"
  end
end

# ./bar.rb
class Bar
  include Foo
end
```

i would expect the output of this to be:

```
the class that included Foo was defined in this directory: ../
```

is this possible? if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes can be defined in many files, so there is no real answer to your question. On the other hand, you can tell from which file the `include Foo` was made:

```
# ./modules/foo.rb
module Foo
  def self.included(obj)
    path, = caller[0].partition(":")
    puts "the module Foo was included from this file: #{path}"
  end
end
```

This will be the path you're looking for, unless there's a `MyClass.send :include, Foo` somewhere else then where MyClass was defined...

*Note*: For Ruby 1.8.6, `require 'backports'` or change the `partition` to something else.

Comment: thanks! that's a good way for me to get the functionality i wanted. i was worried about the multi-file issue. knowing where the include was made is what i need. :)

Answer (score 3):

There's no built-in way to find out where a module or class was defined (afaik). In Ruby, you can re-open a module/class at any time and any place and add or change behavior. This means, there's usually no single place where a module/class gets defined and such a method wouldn't make sense.

In your application, you can however stick to some convention so that you are able to construct the source filename. E.g. in Rails, a pages controller is by convention named PagesController and gets defined primarily in the file app/controllers/pages_controller.rb.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
module Foo
  def self.included(obj)
    obj_dirname = File.expand_path(File.dirname($0)) 
    puts "the class that included Foo was defined in this directory: #{obj_dirname}"
  end
end
```

Edit: changed according to comments.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Replace `__FILE__` with `$0`. With bar.rb in ~/tmp and foo.rb in ~/tmp/modules, this is the output when I run bar.rb: "the class that included Foo was defined in this directory: /Users/xxx/tmp"

Answer (score 0):

```
module Foo

  def self.included obj
    filename = obj.instance_eval '__FILE__'
    dirname = File.expand_path(File.dirname(filename))
    puts "the class that included Foo was defined in this directory: #{dirname}"
  end

end
```

Comment: That doesn't work. `__FILE__` is not a method, and `instance_eval` returns `"(eval)"`